# R: Suppress base graphics plot but return plot as object

Tags: r, graphics

I have a function that both returns some statistics and makes a plot using R base graphics. I want to suppress the plotting from that function and instead return the plot as an object, so that plotting or not can be controlled from outside the function.

I've tried:

Using the `gridGraphics` package I can convert a base graphics plot to an object as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583849/save-a-plot-in-an-object):

```
plot(1:10)
grid.echo()
a = grid.grab()
grid.draw(a)
```

The remaining problem is that `plot()` command draws the plot that I want to suppress. Thus I tried to suppress it by plotting to a device in a temp file like [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363266/how-can-i-suppress-the-creation-of-a-plot-while-calling-a-function-in-r) suggests. Code becomes:

```
ff = tempfile()
svg(filename = ff)
plot(1:10)
grid.echo()
a = grid.grab()
dev.off()
unlink(ff)
```

but now, `grid.echo()` can not find any graphics to echo, and throws warning:

```
Warning message:
In grid.echo.recordedplot(recordPlot(), newpage, prefix, device) :
  No graphics to replay
```

I've traced this problem back to `grid.echo()` not being able to echo graphics from other devices than the Rstudio default device, regardless of being in a temp file or not. This is in itself strange, since `grid.echo()` docs says it echoes graphics from the current device, not mentioning any restrictions.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem of suppressing base graphics plot and returning it as object, either by suggesting how to fix my broken attempt, or with another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LocoGris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10944942/locogris) solved the problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280746/copy-plot-with-grid-echo-from-non-default-device) related question about the behaviour of `grid.echo`.

The following code will plot the unwanted graphics output into a tempfile, save the plot as a grid object using `grid.echo` and `grid.grab` before unlinking the tempfile so that only the plot object remains, thereby producing the besired behaviour:

```
ff = tempfile()
svg(filename = ff)
plotfun <- function() plot(1:10)
grid.echo(plotfun)
a = grid.grab()
dev.off()
unlink(ff)
```

The difference to code in question is that the plotting in R base graphics is put into a function and passed to `grid.echo`, instead of relying on `grid.echo` to automatically find what it needs from the current device.

Potentially useful note: `grid.echo` will plot two times, which can be seen if using regular `svg()` without tempfiles, as two files will appear with the same plot. I assume that the first plot is in R base graphics and the second one is the echo using the grid system.